# The Android emulator is out of view, how can I move it?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I used an additional display with my laptop and moved the Android emulator there. It seems to remember the location even if the display is not connected anymore.

Is there any way to reset the position of the window so it becomes visible again?

Comment: Specifying your operating system here might have been helpful. I'm glad you fixed your issue all the same

Answer (score 69, accepted):

more exactly from your home directory

(on Linux: `$HOME/`  on Windows: `C:\Users\<your user>` )
 go into

```
.android/avd/<image name>
```

open the file ***emulator-user.ini*** and set 
window.x and window.y to 0.

```
window.x = 0
window.y = 0
```

If you don't see the hidden dir `.android` on Linux press `Ctrl+H` and from Windows select View>Options>View (Tab) and select *"Show hidden files"*

---

***EDIT:***

If the file emulator-user.ini doesn't exist, close the emulator window, then check the avd directory again. This is because emulator-user.ini is generated after the first run of the emulator.

Comment: Why i can not find the file emulator-user.ini under the path

Comment: If you can't find emulator-user.ini, just create it

Answer (score 195):

You can use this Method for moving any window that is off the screen in a windows environment.

- First Select the window either by Alt-Tab or Click clicking it
- Press Alt & Space keys together
- Press "M" or select it with the mouse Use  your arrow keys to move the Window
- Press Enter to exit

This is far easier than editing any files.

Comment: Pefect. Use arrow keys at the end.

Comment: Worked fine on Win7 x64.  Thanks!

Comment: Using the arrow keys worked for me while editing the emulator-user.ini file stopped working (tried both API 21 & 22 AVDs).

Comment: Sorry, I know this is the standard Windows short-cut for moving windows, however, for some reason I'm not able to move my AVD window at all. It's immovable. :(

Comment: Alt+space worked for me using taskbar Thanks

Answer (score 20):

It was easy. I  opened the avd location and the  file emulator-user.ini  contains the location and can be changed.

Maybe someone else needs it.

Comment: I had this problem with Windows 7 and the answer fixed my situation. I only wish I knew how I'd moved the emulator out of view initially... It was frustrating because Alt-Tab showed the emulator in its full glory, tantalizingly close but out of reach :)

Comment: The arrow keys worked (my mouse did not) using Alt + space answer.

Comment: ^ mouse will only work once the Title Bar is onscreen, so arrow keys until its onscreen and then you "should" be able to do the rest of the movement with your mouse. 2015 \m/

Answer (score 15):

Alt+Space then use the arrow keys

Comment: Bingo. I'm able to move the window with arrows after selecting Move. I can move the window to another screen with the mouse.

Answer (score 6):

At First Go-to your **AVD MANAGER SECTION** & Click On It ,Then

[image]

1. Right Click on Your Virtual Mobile & See **"Show On Disk "** & Click on it
2. Then you see Your AVD Drive & see `emulator-user.ini` & Then `open` it .
3. set value **`window.x = 0 window.y = 0`**
4. **Close & Restart Your Project & AVD Also** .

Answer (score 3):

Alt + Space works just fine.
The emulator-user.ini answer did not work for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For windows 10 users, just press

```
ctrl + alt + up_arrow_key
```

Side note:

```
ctrl + alt + left_arrow_key
ctrl + alt + right_arrow_key
ctrl + alt + down_arrow_key
```

this will rotate your screen

Answer (score 0):

> For Windows operating system
> Control panel -> Programs -> Turn window features on or off -> check Telnet client and Telnet server option -> ok

now open your cmd as administrator
come to your  'c' drive path using cd\

> C:\Users\Harin>cd\
>
> C:\telnet localhost 5554

now it's open new window
write

> window scale 0.3

here 5554 is your emulator screen number
and 0.3 is your screen size, you can change as you want for example 0.2 or 0.4 etc

Answer (score 0):

if you see the toolbar next to it but don't see the emulator, click on the zoom button and it will appear.

Answer (score 0):

In my case none of the answers related to move the emulator window worked.

To make it work with "scale and layout" NOT in 100% (as I had in my case) I had to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58380843/2469583)

Also did this (not sure if necessary, but in case somebody needs it):

I had to right click on desktop, then "display properties", then "Advanced scaling settings", then set the scaling to 100% (I had it in 250%), then open the emulator and resize it as small as possible and put it in the top left of my screen. Then "Turn off custom scaling and sign out", then I could see and resize my emulator window.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mac and you aren't able to move the emulator by normal dragging the emulator then do this.

1. Display Mission Control using <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>arrow up</kbd>.
2. Move the emulator to your new window/monitor.
3. click on the emulator or <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>arrow down</kbd>

done!