# Android emulator stays minimized (eclipse, windows 7)

Tags: eclipse, android-emulator

This is an issue that happens to me just sometimes, most of the times the emulator works ok.

[screenshot of the problem with the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVKZZ.jpg)

The thing is, that the emulator starts but it can not be maximized. It doesn't matter if you click on its "window" from the Tasklist at the bottom or you try to force it to maximize/make it go to the front from the Task-manager; it just doesn't react to it.
In the little window that appears when you have the mouse over the task (see screenshot), you can even watch the emulator starting and waiting for the interaction with the clock and so on, but it is not accessible.

Any ideas?!

Comment: Check if the emulator window somehow became out of view (check emulator-user.ini in AVD path). See the answer for question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572485/the-android-emulator-is-out-of-view-how-can-i-move-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue after forcing the emulator to close during debugging.

To fix the problem, try changing the screen resolution of the virtual device under `Edit` in the AVD manager and then launch the virtual device.

This fixed the issue for me and I was able to revert to the original resolution without any problems.

Comment: I haven't got this problem lately, so I'm not sure if your answer would help me, but I marked it as accepted because I also think it might have something with the screen size and the scaling that sometimes I applied. Thanks.