# Android studio - the emulator is stacked outside of the screen

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

My android emulator won't show the minimize or close button, It's stuck to the left of my screen and I can't drag it to the right or anywhere.

Comment: Change the default values Best solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572485/the-android-emulator-is-out-of-view-how-can-i-move-it

Comment: 2022 Android Studio Dolphin: Run Emulator > Click Settings Icon (Top-Right) > View Mode > Window > Done!

Answer (score 85, accepted):

have you tried moving it with the keyboard?
if you're using Windows -

Press **ALT+SPACE+M** together. You are now in Move mode. You might have to use the arrows **UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT** to move your window.

press ***Enter*** to exit Move mode.

Comment: Aviram just tried it, nothing happened just stays like this
http://prntscr.com/6cxgqi

Comment: sorry it didn't help. I would recommend adding a screenshot to the question. (it didn't opened for me)

Comment: Another program started when i pressed Alt + space in the background, just changed the Hotkey for that program then I was able to move the emulator perfectly Thanks Aviram :)

Answer (score 18):

Press **ALT + SPACE + M** and move the windows by press **UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT** and it will work.

Have fun ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for solving such a crazy situation... This is Google we are talking about and yet such a frustrating situation... ALT + Space + M and then just arrows... too easy

Comment: Yes, who knows why this is left out of their solving objectives? :)

Answer (score 4):

Press *ALT+spacebar* then release and press *m* to get into Move mode.  *Use the **arrow keys** to move the window.* Press *Enter* to exit Move mode.

Answer (score 1):

sleepless is correct and it worked for me.
I have Windows 8.1

1. go to your users folder.
2. go to /.android
3. go to /avd
4. go to /[emulator].avd
5. edit emulator-user.ini
   change the y to 10 or more and save.

To resize the emulator while running:

1. go to Control Panel
2. Click on Programs
3. Click on Turn Windows features on or off
4. check Telnet Client and Telnet Server.  hit 'OK'
5. Run -> cmd
6. type 'cd\'
7. type 'telnet localhost 5554'
8. type 'help' to get a list of commands
9. type 'window scale .3' or .2 or whatever size you want and close

Thanks to E Angkor

Answer (score 1):

No above option work for me.But while i trying that my whole scree orient portail in windows 7.When i switch it back emulator automatically orient correctly.Actually short cut rotate screen in window is ALT + CTRL + ARROW KEYS in my system.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches:
1. remove the emulator-user.ini file under the .avd/ folder or the
 $HOME/.android/ folder and try again;
2. change the values of x and y in the above file to be >= 10

Answer (score 0):

**ALT+spacebar** and then **"Agrandir pour remplir le bureau"** in french **"Zoom to fill the office"** **worked for me**.

Comment: Following the steps allowed me to move the nexus 5 window to access top content