# Android emulator window top bar out of the screen

Tags: windows-7, android-emulator

I am using windows 7 when my windows toolbar on the right hand side, the android emulator out of the screen. This causes me cannot move the window.

How to fix this

[image]

Comment: Change the toolbar position.

Comment: @PrerakSola  sorry, just realize it is not toolbar problem. The emulator top bar always out of screen even if I create small size emulator.

Comment: I also faced this problem.I made the emulator ration lower so that I can see the full emulator.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572485/the-android-emulator-is-out-of-view-how-can-i-move-it                   --  open the file emulator-user.ini and set window.x and window.y to 100

Comment: For your information, i switched to genymotion. it is more better than android AVD. how funny it is better than official. LOL

Comment: I had the same problem and I thought to myself "REALLY?! I have to google this shit - it's not even a programming problem". The simple things with Android - still difficult.

Comment: Change the default value Best solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572485/the-android-emulator-is-out-of-view-how-can-i-move-it

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Press the Alt-Space keys and you should get the window with the option allowing you to move the emulator window. Then move it e.g. using keyboard arrows.
It works for me on Windows 7.

Comment: Very easy and useful solution. (y)

Comment: Works for me on Windows 8.1.  The key is using keyboard, not mouse.  For my case, the mouse cannot move the emulator out of the stuck position.  However, once it is out of the stuck position, mouse can be used to drag it.

Comment: This solution is better

Comment: very nice, can't figure it out

Answer (score 9):

Try to change your screen resolution temporarily (e.g. to a lower value). Then switch back to your original screen resolution. That should do the trick. Worked for me on Windows 8.

Comment: The accepted answer didn't work for me though this one did. (Windows 10)

Comment: @noob - I had this same problem in Windows 8.1 and posted the answer that is a bit easier than changing the resolution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. When emulator will start, you need to start the same one again, so you will have two running, but the second one should pop up normally and you can move with it. After this, you can close the first one and then it will work for your next time too.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in Windows 8.1.

You can also solve this by:

1. holding the shift key
2. while right-clicking the taskbar icon for the emulator

When you do that you'll get a different menu than if you only right-click the icon.

It'll look like this:
[image]

Just click the Move menu item and then an four-way arrow will appear over the android emulator window.
Use your arrow keys to move the Anroid Emulator window.

**NOTE:** If you click the mouse, you'll lose the four-way arrow and have to do the first steps again.