# Emulator Window Out of view in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I just installed android studio after clean installation of my Windows 8 , A month back it worked fine but now after a clean install its occurs a problem that emulator windows didn't set on my screen, I searched over web and on stack overflow but didn't get any valuable answer to solve my issue, I follow this solution [android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572485/the-android-emulator-is-out-of-view-how-can-i-move-it) and also edit my emulator.ini file but it didn't help me to resolve my problem.

Any Help would be appreciated  !