# Android AVD emulator scaling issue in windows 10

Tags: android, android-emulator, windows-10, android-virtual-device, android-studio-2.3

I'm on windows 10, Andorid Studio 2.3.3, I created a an android avd with the below configuration but the display won't scale properly, the display will be only in a corner.

```
 Name: 4_WVGA_Nexus_S_API_23 
 CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86) 
 Path: C:\Users\user\.android\avd\4_WVGA_Nexus_S_API_23.avd 
 Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 22) Skin: 480x800 
 SD Card: C:\Users\user\.android\avd\4_WVGA_Nexus_S_API_23.avd\sdcard.img hw.dPad: no 
 runtime.network.speed: full 
 hw.accelerometer: yes 
 hw.device.name: 4in WVGA (Nexus S) 
 vm.heapSize: 48 
 skin.dynamic: yes 
 hw.device.manufacturer: Generic 
 hw.gps: yes 
 hw.initialOrientation: Portrait 
 skin.path.backup: _no_skin 
 image.androidVersion.api: 22 
 hw.audioInput: yes image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-22\google_apis\x86\ 
 tag.id: google_apis 
 showDeviceFrame: no 
 hw.camera.back: emulated 
 hw.mainKeys: yes 
 AvdId: 4_WVGA_Nexus_S_API_23 
 hw.camera.front: emulated 
 hw.lcd.density: 240 
 avd.ini.displayname: 4 
 WVGA (Nexus S) API 23 hw.gpu.mode: auto 
 hw.device.hash2: MD5:380daa949ffbfa516f53f3f58637c4b3 hw.ramSize: 512 
 hw.trackBall: no PlayStore.enabled: false hw.battery: yes 
 hw.cpu.ncore: 2 
 hw.sdCard: yes 
 tag.display: Google APIs 
 runtime.network.latency: none 
 hw.keyboard: yes hw.sensors.proximity: yes disk.dataPartition.size: 800M 
 hw.sensors.orientation: yes 
 avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8 
 hw.gpu.enabled: yes
```

[image]

Any idea on how the scaling issue can be resolved ?

Answer (score 3):

Ok so you need to disable windows 10 scaling for this app. While its running find it in task manager.[image: The Emulator Process] Right click on "Android Emulator - [Device Name]"[image: A Right Click (Slightly Miss aligned)] and chose open file location. You should now see the folder with the emulator exe highlighted. [image: Emulator Folder] Now Right click on the exe and open properties. Then go to the "Compatibility" tab.[image: Compatibility Tab] Now open "Change high DPI settings". Here's where the magic happens. Use these settings, Of note is scaling preformed by "System" this means that we wont trust qemu to do the scaling (which it ignores and causes the problem) [image]

Comment: Not that it will be blurry, with big pixels. But at-least the mouse aligns with where the image is.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. In your Virtual Device Configuration window, set *Emulated Performance* to *Software*

It seems that if you're using Hardware Acceleration the scaling goes all wonky.

Good luck[image: ![Virtual Device Configuration]

*Note: From what I've been able to test myself, SDK Level 24 is the highest you can go with Software acceleration. If you try running at SDK 26 or 27 you'll get some weird artifacts or lines across your simulator screen.
This solution isn't ideal, but at least it's more usable than the mini-screen you get with hardware acceleration.

Comment: Sorry, but it's really not a solution. Emulator without hardware acceleration is not usable at all.