# Android Emulator UI too large on Windows 10 20H2

Tags: windows, android-studio, user-interface, android-emulator

I am using Android Studio 4.1.1 on Windows 10 20H2 with Hyper-V enabled on a computer with high DPI. Recently whenever I launch an AVD, the UI of the emulated device window becomes extremely large and impossible to use (as in the following screenshot). Other windows (including the AVD manager and the Android Studio itself) remains normal.

[image: Screenshot]

I have not used the emulator for a while, but I can make sure that the UI issue did not exist before I update my Windows to 20H2. I have also found similar questions on Stack Overflow (including [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847429/android-avd-emulator-scaling-issue-in-windows-10)), but the existing answers suggesting overriding its high DPI behavior does not work for me, because when I apply this setting, the emulator screen becomes so blurry that I cannot even recognize the texts on the screen.

How can I solve (or work around) this issue? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the scaling issue when using the Hardware rendering by simply making windows override the scaling setting. How?, it's very easy. Simply locate the .exe file for the emulator that you are using, (e.g. "qemu-system-armel.exe" for ARM and "qemu-system-x86_64.exe" for x86). To make sure which .exe file, just run the emulator then use task manager to locate the .exe file is running, see the screenshot. locate the .exe file using task manager

In my case it was in this location:

```
 C:\Users[Username]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe
```

[image]